# Proof that Hamiltonicity is not first-order definable

Tags: logic, graph-theory, model-theory

I am looking for a proof for the non-definability, in first order logic, of the exisence of a Hamiltonian cycle (or path) on a graph. It seems it can be proved using Ehrefeucht-Fraïssé games, but I can't manage to do it.
Here are some things  I tried that didn't work:

- Deriving the problem from Eulerian cycles. Tried making the edges into vertices and connecting them in some smart way. Didn't work.
- Deriving from parity. Tried finding a way to build a graph related to a number $n$ such that if $n$ is even, the graph would be Hamiltonian, but if $n$ was odd, it wouldn't.

I suppose deriving the problem from another one (especially those above) may be hard or downright impossible because it would mean translating a $NP$-complete problem to a much simpler one using first-order sentences, which seems wrong.

If someone needs such definitions, an Eulerian path is a path that goes through all edges only once and a Hamiltonian path is one that goes through all vertices once. A cycle is a closed path.

Also, I'm working with finite graphs only.

Comment: I presume you are looking only at *finite* structures - that is, that your problem is "Show that there is no first-order sentence $\varphi$ in the language of graphs such that for every finite graph $G$ we have $G\models\varphi$ iff $G$ has a Hamiltonian path." Is this correct? (Restricting to finite structures is needed to avoid triviality: there is still a notion of Hamiltonian path for infinite graphs, but they can only exist in *countable* graphs, and so compactness gives a silly answer to this version of the question.)

Comment: The cycle graph $C_n$ is Hamiltonian, the graph $2C_n$ (union of two vertex-disjoint copies of $C_n$) is not even connected. Here are a couple of ideas to try. (1) Given $m\in\mathbb N$, use E-F game to show that $C_n$ and $2C_n$ are $m$-equivalent if $n$ is sufficiently large. (2) The theory of $2$-regular graphs is $\aleph_1$-categorical. Let $G$ be the $2$-regular graph of cardinality $\aleph_1$, unique up to isomorphism. Any first-order sentence that holds in all the graphs $C_n$ must hold in $G$; likewise any sentence that holds in all the graphs $2C_n$ must hold in $G$.

Comment: Yes. I'm restricting to finite graphs. Thanks for pointing out. I will try these ideas as soon as I can! Thanks for the tips. I'll update with the progress.